# Xcode 5 - Could not build module

Tags: xcode

I've turned on the flag in my project 'Enable Modules (C and ObjectiveC)' and i get 1000+ errors:

> 'Could not build module 'Security' 'Could not build module
>   'Foundation'

etc. etc... for every framework included

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Answer (score 15):

I had same problem with Social.h. Fixed this issue by following [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/24766902#24766902) link..

EDIT:
In case the link breaks in the future, I'm adding the solution quoted from the page

> The real problem here is at Build settings in the session:   Apple
>
> LLVM 5.0 - language - Modules,   we should set Enable Modules (C and
>
> objective c) as NO

[image: example]

Comment: Guys, can someone explain why this works? Seems like the only way to properly add includes from custom frameworks is changing that option. Which doesn't seem very intuitive. Btw thanks a lot for this I have been bashing my head the last 2 hours

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem.Here is what worked for me: 
go to Build settings -> Architecture -> Architectures and change the option to standard architecture ( armv7 , armv7s ).

Mine somehow was changed ( including 64 - bit )

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I don't have 64bit builds turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I had this happen to me unexpectedly when I moved my project into another folder. Changing the location made xCode go bonkers
looking for the files. As soon as I put the project folder back in its original location, all of the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Had an Issue with Parse Framework doing this this on a project.

In: **Apple LLVM 8.0 - Language Modules**

I changed: **Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules** from **No** to **YES** and compiles fine

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If it is useful, none solution proposed here solved my problem "Could not find module Darwin" in Xcode 6.2. Finally I have decided to create a new project and copy my source files, but command line tools option disappear when I tried to create a new project. So, I have reinstalled Command Line Tools from Terminal with the next command "xcode-select --install". All was solved!