# Error importing a Parse the Facebook Wrapper Library from the Parse SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I've read a lot of posts about this type of error. But I use version 1.12, and the issues talked about earlier versions of the Parse SDK.

I find it sort of ridiculous that XCode throws these errors, when using a professionally produced set of libraries (Parse's Facebook interaction libraries).

So I would like to give a set of steps to reproduce the bug:

1. Start a new blank project in XCode.
2. Download the Parse SDK (I don't use Pods). It'll appear in the downloads folder. Now drag and drop it, select "Copy items" so you copy that over into Xcode.

Now in any .h or .m file you want, write:

```
 #import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

Now you get:

"Could not build module 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'"

You also get:

'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAccessToken.h' file not found

What gives?

To be honest I haven't had the time to hack at the second error. I've exclusively hit my head against the wall over the first one.

Comment: Would you please share screenshot for same and Do you imported necessary frameworks define in this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29466751/3077339

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401388/xcode-5-could-not-build-module

Comment: ^ modules already enabled.

Comment: ^^ all libraries imported, still not working after clean.